# How to insert 365 rows and increment date by one day for each row

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a table with the schema like this:

```
date | from_city | to_city | rate_per_mile
```

I want to insert today's rate for a city pair (city1, city2, rate) and create 365 rows for all days starting from today until the next 365 days.

```
date                   | from_city | to_city | rate_per_mile 
-------------------------------------------------------------
DATE(NOW())            | city1     | city2   | 13.23
DATE(NOW()) + 1 day    | city1     | city2   | 13.23
DATE(NOW()) + 2 days   | city1     | city2   | 13.23
DATE(NOW()) + 3 days   | city1     | city2   | 13.23
...
DATE(NOW()) + 365 days | city1     | city2   | 13.23
```

`(date, from_city, to_city)` is the primary key for the table, and I would be updating the table every day, so if a row already exists for the key, it should be replaced.

What is the best possible way to do these insert/updates? Worst case since I have to do this from a java program, I'll have to create 365 rows and do a big bulk insert:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES 
  (DATE(NOW()), city1, city2, 13.23),
  (DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL '1' day), city1, city2, 13.23),
  (DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL '2' day), city1, city2, 13.23),
  ...
```

Questions:

1. What is the best way to do this?
2. In such situations, can I avoid these inserts and create views instead that would return the latest available date projected for next 365 days for each city pair? How to create such a view?

Comment: Are those rates different each day? If not I'd question the design of 1 row per day and would probably use something like ranges, i.e. put start (and if needed end) dates. If you want to get the rate for a certain day you'd then query for the row whose start date is nearest to that day but still before it or the same day. That way your example with all days having the same rate would just result in 1 entry.

Comment: @Thomas good point, but unfortunately yes, they will be different every day.

Comment: Perhaps the city pairs should be moved to a parent table? Each row in `city_pair` table has zero, one, or more rows in `rate` table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()` for this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (date, from_city, to_city, rate_per_mile)
select g.dt::date, 'city1', 'city2', 13.12
from generate_series(current_date, current_date + 364, interval '1 day') as g(dt);
```

Comment: @daltonfury42: Do you want 365 days or do you actually want 1 year.  They are not the same; 365 days is correct approximately 75 percent of the time. If you always want a full year then use *generate_series(current_date, current_date + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day', interval '1 day) as g(dt)*

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to do this from Java, create a loop, and use batching for better performance.

```java
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
String fromCity = "city1";
String toCity = "city2";
BigDecimal ratePerMile = new BigDecimal("13.23");

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("...")) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO my_table ( date, from_city, to_city, rate_per_mile ) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        for (int daysToAdd = 0; daysToAdd <= 365; daysToAdd++) {
            LocalDate date = today.plusDays(daysToAdd);
            stmt.setObject(1, date);
            stmt.setString(2, fromCity);
            stmt.setString(3, toCity);
            stmt.setBigDecimal(4, ratePerMile);
            stmt.addBatch();
        }
        stmt.executeBatch();
    }
}
```

If the JDBC driver doesn't like `LocalDate`, use this line instead:

```java
stmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I will have to do if there is no pure SQL/DB solution to it.